# Multiple Questions about meteor pub/sub

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

I'm new to Meteor. I intend to add a new document to collection(client+server) and let the server pick the change. Then when i need to update my template with the sum total of all the inserts/updates/removes on the collection, i publish the collection from server and subscribe to it on client.

1. Once we publish something, can we subscribe, stop subscription and then subscribe again? I intend to subscribe only when the 'add document' button on client is pressed. In the function that processes such a click, I intend to insert, then call the method on server to publish and then subscribe. Is that a proper way of going about this?
2. Is there a way to simplify this? like i put the insert or update of a document in to the client side collection and just let Meteor deal with updating the server side collection and then updating the client side template?
3. It appears to me, from what little I learnt, that for some use-cases that I have, need publishing at each click. I've done this to update the reactive table to list the current folder's contents each time a folder is selected. So a Publish on server checks for contents in the collection for that folder as parent and returns it. Each new select of a folder means new publish. Can something be done to simplify this?

Comment: have you done any of the tutorials?

Comment: I did. All of them show the simple how-to of publish-subscribe. I have not found answers to how many times i can unsubscribe and resubscribe etc questions that i asked.

Comment: you can keep changing your subscriptions

Comment: 1.  yes, 2. The whole point of meteor 3. keep updating your subscription with however you want to filter your collection

Comment: write some code, see how it goes, then ask a question if you run into trouble with that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating one of the core concepts behind Meteor: reactivity. Here are some clarifications to your 3 questions though:

1. This isn't something you need to worry about. Once you publish a
   collection, or subset of your collection, it's published to all
   connected clients. When you're subscribed to said publication, any
   updates that are made are reactively pulled down to all connected
   clients with that subscription. So if I add a document to a
   collection I'm subscribed to, say a task list, it's going to be
   reactively sent down to any client that's subscribed to it,
   including my own.
2. Meteor has something called latency compensation which immediately
   updates the user interface, and as long as it matches what the
   server says, the insert appears to happen instantaneously. This
   behavior is what Meteor does by default if you insert to a
   collection from the client, as long as your insert is approved (i.e.
   as long as the client has permissions to insert to that collection).
3. You don't need to republish every time. As long as you're publishing
   the documents in the collection you need, and you're subscribed on
   the client, any new documents that meet the criteria of your Mongo
   selectors and return statements on the client will be available to
   you and your UI will be updated automatically.